# Quadratic expression equal to zero

Tags: matrices, quadratic-forms

Consider the expression

$$
A^T V A=0
$$

where $V$ is a $l\times l$ strictly negative definite matrix and $A$ is a $l\times 1$ vector.

Is it correct to say

(1) $A^T V A=0$ if and only if $A=0_l$, where $0_l$ is a $l\times 1$ vector of zeros

or

(2) $A^T V A=0$ if and only if $||A||=0$, where $||\cdot ||$ is the norm

?

Comment: You could just try a couple and maybe you will get a hint.  My favorite strictly negative definite matrix is the $1 \times 1$ matrix with single entry $-1$.  The negative of the $2 \times 2$ identity is another good one.  Let $A$ be an arbitrary vector of the right size, multiply the expressions out, and see what happens.